# What are the differences between the two equations relating inflation, real interest rates and nominal interest rates?

Tags: interest-rates, inflation

My lecturer showed two equations to describe the relationship between inflation, nominal and real interest rates, denoted as $I, RN, RR$, respectively.

Then we have the following equations
$$
1+ RR_{1-0} = \frac{1+NR_{1-0}}{1+I_{1-0}} \tag{1}
$$

$$
RR_{1-0} \approx NR_{1-0} - I_{1-0} \tag{2}
$$

My understanding of the two equations is as follows.

$(2)$ becomes an equality once we apply $RR$ in advance on $V_{0}$, where $V_i$ denotes the principal at time $i$. My reasoning for this is:

\begin{equation}\tag{3}
V_1 =V_0 \cdot (1+NR_{1-0}) = V_0 \cdot (1+I_{1-0}) + V_0\cdot RR_{1-0}\\
\implies NR_{1-0} = I_{1-0} + RR_{1-0}
\end{equation}

My troubles comes with when to use $(1)$.

Consider a bond with $PV=1000$ with $RC_{2-0} = 2.5%$. Then the $NPV$ calculation becomes:

$$
1000 = \frac{25}{1+RY_{2-0}} + \frac{1025}{(1+RY_{2-0})^2}
$$

So when we calculate this in terms of $NY$ we get:
$$
1000=\frac{25}{1+NY_{2-0}} + \frac{25(1+I_{2-0}) + 1000(1+I_{2-0})^2}{(1+NY_{2-0})^2}
$$

We get $25$ as we apply the $RC$ on the principal value of 1000 at $t=0$, we get $25(1+I_{2-0})$ as we apply $RC$ on principal at $t=1$, which has undergone inflation.

My questions are:

1. My lecturer wrote "If $RC$ accrues ahead on $V_1$ not $V_0$ then we get $(1)$." How is this the case? Since for the $NPV$ calculation at $t=1$ we're applying $RC$ on $V_0$.
2. Why do we get $1000(1+I_{2-0})^2$? Since we get principal back at $t=2$ and we only know inflation rate of $t=2$ at $t=2+\delta$ where $\delta > 0.$

Comment: What does the abbreviation RC mean here?  Is it the nominal coupon rate?

Comment: This is the real coupon rate.

Comment: Isn’t (2) just the first order approximation to (1)?